# Kinvey-Join data and fetch it

Tags: kinvey

I use the Kinvey backend to store my webapp data. It can be found here: http://www.kinvey.com/
Now I have two collections, the first one contains a unique id and the second has a column which refers to the id-column of the first collection.
Now I would like to join both of them and fetch the data. This seems difficult to me, so could someone give me a hint please?

Thanks in advance,

enne

Answer (score 0):

I'm a part of the engineering organization at Kinvey. We have a data relationship feature that makes it very straightforward for you to establish the relationship that you describe in your Kinvey app backend, and then you can fetch that referenced data in a single call.

In your example, you can query for an entity in the second collection in a manner that will use the id to include the matching entity from the first collection, all as part of the same request. To do so, you can look at our JavaScript library documentation for more detail: http://docs.kinvey.com/js-developers-guide.html#relational_data. We are writing more complete documentation for our REST API now, and looking to release the same functionality for iOS and Android in the near future as well.

If you have any other needs or feature suggestions, feel free to also contact me directly at support@kinvey.com. I would love to hear from you. Thanks.

Comment: Link to releational_data broken